# How can i store an array inside an array?

Tags: java, arrays

Is it possible to declare an array of type `String[]` array.
I think not, so how you go about it?

I have a for loop in which each iteration returns another array of String type. So that i need to store all those arrays.

EDIT:

Can someone tell me how to print out a two dimensional string array.
The problem is `Array[i][j]`, now here `"i"` is fixed but `"j"` keeps changing dpeneding upon the size of array returned in above method.

So how can i proceed further. Any simple printing idea would be a great help.

EDIT:

How can i get the size of `[j]` index. `Array.length;` returns the size of `[i]` index.

EDIT:

Here is how i did it:

```
for (int i=0; i< files.length; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<files[i].length; j++){
            System.out.println("["+i+"]["+j+"] = "+ files[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "the size of [j] index". Every `String[]` in a `String[][]` may have its own, separate length.

Comment: @Karl, So that means there is no way to check out how many elements are stored against each [i]? If this is the case, i can not have any general set of code to display the results. Everytime i get NullPointer Exception. I think i would have to use Linked LIsts here.

Comment: @Karl, you were WRONG. I figured out the way. In each iteration i can use Array[i].length; to get size of [j] index.
I would appreciate if you could avoid giving wrong idea. If you don't know something, please don't raise confusion and time wastage for others.

Comment: I said nothing wrong. Read it again: "Every `String[]` in a `String[][]` may have its own, separate length". That is why, "in each iteration, [you] can use `Array[i].length`" to get the length of **that `String[]`**. I know exactly what I'm talking about, and your time was very well spent, as you figured out what to do. Your terminology was simply a bit off. BTW, NullPointerExceptions have nothing to do with the problem of figuring out how long each row is. They came about because a `String[][]` holds `String[]` objects, and a `String[]` can be null, and `x[i]` is invalid when `x` is null.

Answer (score 2):

You might be referring to 2 dimensional arrays. A very quick tutorial is available [here](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/arrayexamples/two.shtml).

Comment: Thanks, what confused me i thought by multidimensional they are really "multidimensional". It seems in java they really an array of another array.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - it's `String[][]`. You can also have 3-dimensional array with `[][][]`

On the other hand, you can use a `List<List<X>>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[][] stringArrayArray = new String[5][];
stringArrayArray[0] = new String[10];
```

etc

Comment: stringArrayArray[0][] = new String[10] wrong usage. it should be like that stringArrayArray[0] = new String[10]

Comment: I think two nested for loops can do the job. How you go about checking the size of 2nd index in a two dimensinal array.

Comment: @Gursel Koca - Thanks.  I was fixing it as you were commenting.

Comment: @David - The second dimension can vary for each member of the first.  That is, stringArrayArray[0].length could be 4 and stringArrayArray[1].length could be 19.

Answer (score 1):

2D arrays are arrays of arrays see here http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/cs231/lectures/chapter9/arrays2d.htm

Answer (score 1):

It can be done.

```
String[] array = new String[10]; //Array for ten String objects.

String[][] arrayOfArrays = new String[10][]; //Array for ten String arrays.


arrayOfArrays[0] = array; // Under index 0 we assign the reference to array.
```

Another approach is to use List class.

```
   List<String[]> listofArrays = new ArrayList<String[]>();

   listofArrays.add(array):
```